# Is RAM-as-a-service standard for dedicated hosting?

Tags: hardware

Our company has an eight-core dedicated box with 3GB of memory, which we use for a series of tasks (some legacy custom database apps, WordPress MU hosting, etc.,).

Our MySQL user has recently been hogging CPU cycles, so we're working with our hosting provider to optimize some databases (and will probably change some application code as well), but the hosting company is also suggesting an additional gigabyte of memory, for understandable reasons.

My question is this: Is it the industry standard for the provider to charge for that extra gigabyte as an additional $20 monthly fee? I think of memory installation as a one-time parts and labor expense that shouldn't add much to the overall maintenance cost of the machine, but I might just be behind the times.

I'm curious about what other people have experienced with this type of thing. Feel free to link me to another post -- I've sifted through several months of hardware questions on here, but I may have missed something (so apologies if this is redundant).

Comment: More RAM will pull slightly more power, but not $20/month worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it depends on the service but **in general** any sort of customization to the advertized model costs more.  I suspect they already have some servers set up with 4 Gb but maybe not that offering.  The fee seems a little heavy so I'd ask them what they suggest to reduce the fee- "before you move" so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen vendors that charge a monthly fee for RAM (esp virtual servers); but never as much as $20/GB/mo.

Comment: Thanks. This answer helps me gain some perspective on an area with which I'm still hazy.